# Feature detection (Empty descriptor during the second debugging)

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, flann

I'm trying to find an object at the video from usb camera.
Code:

```
for (;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; 

    Mat img_scene = frame;

    if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data) 
    {
        string message = " Error reading ";
        readme(message);
    }

    int minHessian = 400;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

    detector.detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
    detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

    extractor.compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
    extractor.compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);


    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    vector< DMatch > matches;

    descriptors_object.convertTo(descriptors_object, CV_32F);
    descriptors_scene.convertTo(descriptors_scene, CV_32F);
    if (descriptors_object.empty())
        cvError(0, "MatchFinder", "1st descriptor empty", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    if (descriptors_scene.empty())
        cvError(0, "MatchFinder", "2nd descriptor empty", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);
```

After restarting of PC this code works properly. However, the next tries are unsuccsessfull, because of descriptors_scene is empty.
If comment `if (descriptors_scene.empty())`, I receive an error:
Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0) in cv::flann::buildIndex...
I tried to find a solution and I found two suggestions:
1) Convert to another type ( using `descriptors_object.convertTo(descriptors_object, CV_32F);`) -Done, but no luck.
2) restart PC. It works and its ridiculous.

Id appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be related to your problem - `img_object` never gets set.

Comment: it looks to me like you are not closing down the camera interface correctly and the program is holding open links to it, not allowing the next version to open the camera aswell. If your program is crashing then this could be why, if not try adding cap.release() at the end

Comment: @GPPK 
Very strange. I added it at the end and it doesn't work during the first debug after restart too. The same error.